# How to import a data frame in RSQLite with specifying column's constrains?

Tags: r, dataframe, create-table, rsqlite

I am trying to put a large data frame into a new table of a database. It could be done simply done via:

```
dbWriteTable(conn=db,name="sometablename",value=my.data)
```

However, I want to specify the Primary keys, foreign keys and the column Types like Numeric, Text and so on.

Is there any thing I can do? Should I create a table with my columns first and then add the data frame into it?

Answer (score 1):

RSQlite assumes you have already your data.frame table all set before writing it to disk. There is not much to specify in the writing query. So, I visualise two ways, either before firing a query to write it, or after. I usually write the table from R to disk, then I polish it using dbGetQuery to alter table attributes. The only problem with this workflow is that Sqlite has very limited feature for altering tables.